# if statement never executed

Tags: java, joptionpane

Why doesn't this code enter into the if statement?

```
public class GradeCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         *  A 900 - 1000(90% to 100%)   B 800 - 899(80% to 89%)     
         *  C 700 - 799(70% to 79%)     D 600 - 699(60% to 69%)     
         *  F 599 and below (Below 60%)
         */

        String Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name: ");
        String pointsEarned = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the points earned: ");
        String possiblePoints = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the total points possible: ");

        double pe = Double.parseDouble(pointsEarned);
        double pp = Double.parseDouble(possiblePoints);

        double grade = (pe/pp)*100;
        char LetterGrade;

        if(grade>=900){
            LetterGrade = 'A';
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Name + " your grade percentage you earned is " + grade + "%" + " and you for an " + LetterGrade, "Your Grades", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can hear the debugger begging you to use him..

Comment: Maybe you want to multiply by 1000 instead of 100, `double grade = (pe/pp)*1000;`

Comment: well... If its not throwing any error, then the only reason your "if block" will not execute is because grade<900.. Print the value of grade as soon as you calculate it.

Comment: @peeskillet I'd argue that the condition ought to be `if(grade>=90)`, since it's a percentage. But either method has the same result.

Comment: pe = 100 pp = 10 and it entered the if block. What are your test inputs?

Comment: You can trigger the if-statement fine if you enter 10 then 1 when prompted for points. Your logic is just wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot people. Debugging did solve the problem.

Comment: I think it will help future visitors solve their problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have calculated percentage that will not be above 100.Therefore just change if condition to
    if (grade>=90)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply debug and see what happens there.Add else block and see value of grade.

```
if(grade>=900){
     LetterGrade = 'A';
     // ....
}else{
     System.out.print(grade);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grade variable is a percentage and you are comparing it as if it were the score you calculated the percentage on.  So it looks like what you want is just to use `pe` instead of the `grade` variable.

```
if(pe>=900){
```

then only calculate percentage when displaying

```
double percentage = (pe/pp)*100
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Name + " your grade percentage you earned is " + percentage + "%" + " and you for an " + LetterGrade, "Your Grades", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Either that or consider `grade` variable as percentage when testing it

```
 if (grade>=90) //90%
```

**Also**

Variables should always start with a lowercase letter so `LetterGrade` should be `letterGrade`

Answer (score 0):

### That's how I solved it.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class GradeCalculator

{
public static void main(String[] args)


{
    boolean exitLoop = false;

    while(exitLoop == false)
    {
        String Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name: ");

        String pointsEarned = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the points earned: ");

        String possiblePoints = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the total points possible: ");

        double pe = Double.parseDouble(pointsEarned);
        double pp = Double.parseDouble(possiblePoints);

        double grade = (pe*100)/pp;
        double Lgrade = pe;
        char LetterGrade;

        if(Lgrade >= 900)
        {
            LetterGrade = 'A';
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Name + " your grade percentage you earned is " + grade + "%" + " and you got an " + LetterGrade, "Your Grades", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } else if (Lgrade <899 && Lgrade >=800)
        {
            LetterGrade = 'B';
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Name + " your grade percentage you earned is " + grade + "%" + " and you got an " + LetterGrade, "Your Grades", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } else if (Lgrade <799 && Lgrade >=700)
        {
            LetterGrade = 'C';
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Name + " your grade percentage you earned is " + grade + "%" + " and you got an " + LetterGrade, "Your Grades", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } else if (Lgrade <699 && Lgrade >=600)
        {
            LetterGrade = 'D';
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Name + " your grade percentage you earned is " + grade + "%" + " and you got an " + LetterGrade, "Your Grades", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } else if(Lgrade <599)
        {
            LetterGrade = 'F';
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Name + " your grade percentage you earned is " + grade + "%" + " and you got an " + LetterGrade, "Your Grades", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }

        int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to run the program again?", "Yes or No", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if(selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            exitLoop = false;
        } 
        else
        {
            exitLoop = true;
        }
    }


}
```

}